# Exception "Type Resources.ResourceSet is not defined" after adding MySQL via NUGET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, resources

I added a reference to MySql to my project via NUGET, and as soon as I restarted the project, the exception `Type 'Resources.ResourceSet' is not defined` was thrown in the method below:

```
   Public Function GetMyResourcesDictionary() As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim ItemDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim ItemEnumerator As System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator
        Dim ItemResourceSet As Resources.ResourceSet '>>>>>>>EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        Dim ResourceNameList As New List(Of String)

        ItemResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"), True, True)

        'Get the enumerator for My.Resources 
        ItemEnumerator = ItemResourceSet.GetEnumerator

        Do While ItemEnumerator.MoveNext
            ResourceNameList.Add(ItemEnumerator.Key.ToString)
        Loop

        For Each resourceName As String In ResourceNameList
            ItemDictionary.Add(resourceName, GetItem(resourceName))
            ImageList1.Images.Add(GetItem(resourceName))
        Next

        ResourceNameList = Nothing

        Return ItemDictionary
    End Function
```

What do I need to do to resolve this exception?

Comment: The most likely issue is a name clash. I'm guessing that you had previously imported a namespace somewhere that `Resources` was a child namespace of. Due to the changes you've made, `Resources` is probably now being interpreted as something other than that child namespace. There may be other options but you could fully-qualify that type instead of relying on a namespace import, e.g. `Dim ItemResourceSet As SomeParentNamespace.Resources.ResourceSet`. You could afford to do a bit of research and get a better understanding of how namespaces and namespace imports work.

Comment: That said, your code is unnecessarily verbose anyway, and there's no need for you to specify that type. Just let it be inferred, i.e. use `Dim ItemResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"), True, True)`. Declaring variables on one line and then setting them on a separate line immediately after might be what beginners get taught to make things obvious but it's not really how you write "real" code. Declare your variables where you need them and initialise them on the same line if possible.

Comment: I deleted the first definition and modified the 2nd definition to read: `Dim ItemResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en"), True, True)`, which now works.